# Resolve lack of access in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, password, keychain

I was trying to show a password in Keychain Access, so I put my password in to view it.  It then displayed this message: "The provided password did not unlock this keychain, or access has been limited to a particular user account."  My account is the administrator account, so I don't know what could be causing this.  Thanks.

Comment: do you have other users ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yeah, I do.

Comment: What keychain is the password stored in? Also, can you view its access controls (double-click it in Keychain Access, then click the Access Control tab)?

Comment: that would mean that the other user is still logged in, so log it out.

Comment: @Buscar웃 is there a way to log that account out without knowing the password?

Comment: not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

You can log it out without the password. First press command+space and search activity monitor and press enter, then in the search bar in the corner search "loginwindow" without quotations and double click on the one that has the other users name by it. After that you should see a quit option. click it and it will give you 3 choices. Cancel, force quit, and quit. i recommend only force quitting if it isn't responding or if it doesn't work with regular quit. Also, this deletes any unsaved files and/or open tabs you have without saving them, so you might lose some data. About the Keychain password, i have the same question.